# Calling a static function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, static

How would I call the static function `calculator()`?. I know a static function does not need an instance of the class to be called. However, trying the following wont work:

```js
class TaxCalculator {
  static calculator(total) {
    return total * .05;
  }
}

new TaxCalculator().calculator(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function in a static context, i.e. directly on the class itself, and not on an instance of the class:

```js
class TaxCalculator {
  static calculator(total) {
    return total * .05;
  }
}


console.log(TaxCalculator.calculator(50));
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying at it works but in the quiz i was doing i was given the following options. addTax(50) 

new TaxCalculator().calculator($50), 

new TaxCalculator().calculator(50);

Comment: also calculator(50)

Comment: None of those would work. You're sure it's not a Java question, right? Instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Its from the Linkedin Skills test. Its the only question I got wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can access static method directly with Class name.

```js
class TaxCalculator {
  static calculator(total) {
    return total * .05;
  }
}

  console.log(TaxCalculator.calculator(10000));
```